# Triangle strip and 3d grids

Tags: opengl

i'm learning opengl programming for study purposes and i'm using openscenegraph
wrapper around opengl.

My first goal is to render a 3d grid in which heights data is stored in a file as 2d matrix.
First question:can i use TRIANGLE_STRIP to render that grid which can have concave or convex zones?

Second question: Is there a particular alghoritm to render 3d grids (terrains) for this purpose?

I started from a very simple grid data:

```
10 10 10 10 10
10 10 10 10 10
10 10  5 10 10
10 10 10 10 10
10 10 10 10 10
```

it is a very simple 5x5 heights grid, but the result, using triangle_strip is follow:
[image]

as u can see there is a extra-line that i cant drop from my triangle_Strip algorithm.

the code i used is follow (consider it is openscenegraph code).
in rows and columns vars (int) i store grid dimensions.
data is a `osg::Vec3**` pointer in which previously i read plain values.
m_rpTerrainData is a `osg::ref_ptr<osg::Vec3Array>` in which i load, in correct order (as triangle_strip wants) the vertices.

```
for(x=0;x<rows;x++)
{
    for(y=0;y<columns;y++)
    {

        if(x<rows-1 && y<columns-1){
          this->m_rpTerrainData->push_back(data[x][y]);
          this->m_rpTerrainData->push_back(data[x+1][y]);

        }


                     /*degenerate triangle because we at last of a column*/
         if(x<rows-1 && y==columns-1 ){
           this->m_rpTerrainData->push_back(data[x][y]);
           this->m_rpTerrainData->push_back(data[x+1][y]);
                       this->m_rpTerrainData->push_back(data[x+1][y]);
                       this->m_rpTerrainData->push_back(data[x+1][0]);
        }                       
    }
}
    //drop last element
this->m_rpTerrainData->pop_back();
```

Comment: First question: Yes. Second: What do you mean? What is the algorithm supposed to do? Did you make any progress on that extra line? Your code looks correct. Have you verified that the extra line comes from the grid, and not from some other geometry? Is that really just one line extending from (2,1) to (2,3)? What does it look like when you use x^2+y^2 as the grid value function?

Comment: Doh, I just realized that the extra line simply comes from the degenerate triangles you insert at the end of each row. -.-

Comment: but with TRIANGLE_STRIP i have to produce degenerate triangles at the end of each rows. How can i drop that line?? If i have a flat 2d matrix (all height values are the same) the scene rendered is as i expect, but when i have different heights no, there is always that extra-line.

Answer (score 0):

I admit that I was too lazy to look at your algorithm closely, but if you don't mind not reinventing the wheel, I urge you to use the [NvTristrip library](http://www.nvidia.in/object/nvtristrip_library.html). With this, you can take an indexed mesh and convert it to a trimesh.

You can then create a normal indexed mesh of rectangles, with the your x,y,h coordinates specified at every vertex (where h is the height or 'data' from your matrix). You then convert that indexed mesh to a tristrip using NvTristrip and give this data to OpenScenegraph.

I have myself used NvTristrip with OpenScenegraph and it works fine.

However, I am curious as to why you would need a tristrip in the first place since an indexed mesh seems ideal for your purposes. OpenScenegraph more than happily supports QUAD primitive. This would simplify your work I think.